# Are hammock localizations locally truncated?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, localization, simplicial-categories

Let us take a relative category $(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{W})$, and consider its hammock localization $L_H \mathcal{C}$. It seems to me that for every two objects $X,Y \in \mathcal{C}$ the mapping simplicial set $L_H \mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ has the (strict) right lifting property against all inclusions $\partial \Delta^n \hookrightarrow \Delta^n$ for $n \geq 3$. The reason is the following: let us consider the case $n=3$ for simplicity, the general case is analogous. A diagram of shape $\partial \Delta^n$ means a collection of $n+1$ hammocks of width $n-1$ such that some selected $(n-2)$-faces of these correspond. Therefore, up to unreducing these hammocks, they can all be assumed to be of the same length, so let us consider only one column at a time. For each $i=0,1,2,3$ we have four columns of the form

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>f_1^0>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{12}^0VV @VVw_{12}^0V\\
\bullet @>f_2^0>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{23}^0VV @VVw_{23}^0V\\
\bullet @>f_3^0>> \bullet
\end{CD}
\hspace{30pt}
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>f_0^1>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{02}^1VV @VVw_{02}^1V\\
\bullet @>f_2^1>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{23}^1VV @VVw_{23}^1V\\
\bullet @>f_3^1>> \bullet
\end{CD}
\hspace{30pt}
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>f_0^2>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{01}^2VV @VVw_{01}^2V\\
\bullet @>f_1^2>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{13}^2VV @VVw_{13}^2V\\
\bullet @>f_3^2>> \bullet
\end{CD}
\hspace{30pt}
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>f_0^3>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{01}^3VV @VVw_{01}^3V\\
\bullet @>f_1^3>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{12}^3VV @VVw_{12}^3V\\
\bullet @>f_2^3>> \bullet
\end{CD}
$$

I'm omitting names of objects, a superscript index $i$ just refers to the $i$-th labeled 2-face, a subscript index $i$ refers to the $i$-th row, and a subscript index $ij$ refers to the arrow going from the $i$-th row to the $j$-row. Now let us look at what it means for these wannabe $2$-faces to be assembled into a diagram of shape $\partial \Delta^3$.
For instance, the 0-th face of the 0-th diagram and the 0-th face of the 1st diagram should coincide, and similarly for the other compatibility condtions. This allows us to remove the superscript indices from all $f$'s and from all $v_{ij}$'s and $w_{ij}$'s whenever $i$ and $j$ are consecutive.
Moreover, the 1st face of the 0-th diagram and the 0-th face of the 2nd diagram should coincide, and similarly for others. This means that $v_{13}^2 = v_{23} \circ v_{12}$ and analogously for $w_{13}^2$. This means that we can also remove the subscript indices $ij$ when they are not consecutive and write the corresponding $v$'s and $w$'s in terms of those with consecutive indices. In other words, the above columns may be rewritten as

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>f_1>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{12}VV @VVw_{12}V\\
\bullet @>f_2>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{23}VV @VVw_{23}V\\
\bullet @>f_3>> \bullet
\end{CD}
\hspace{30pt}
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>f_0>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{12}\circ v_{01}VV @VVw_{12} \circ w_{01}V\\
\bullet @>f_2>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{23}VV @VVw_{23}V\\
\bullet @>f_3>> \bullet
\end{CD}
\hspace{30pt}
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>f_0>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{01}VV @VVw_{01}V\\
\bullet @>f_1>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{23} \circ v_{12}VV @VVw_{23} \circ w_{12}V\\
\bullet @>f_3>> \bullet
\end{CD}
\hspace{30pt}
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>f_0>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{01}VV @VVw_{01}V\\
\bullet @>f_1>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{12}VV @VVw_{12}V\\
\bullet @>f_2>> \bullet
\end{CD}
$$

Now consider the column

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>f_0>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{01}VV @VVw_{01}V\\
\bullet @>f_1>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{12}VV @VVw_{12}V\\
\bullet @>f_2>> \bullet\\
@Vv_{23}VV @VVw_{23}V\\
\bullet @>f_3>> \bullet
\end{CD}
$$

whose faces are clearly the four columns above. Reasoning like this for each column, we have constructed a diagram of shape $\Delta^3$ whose restriction to $\partial \Delta^3$ is what we started with.

There should be a mistake in the above argument, in that we know that there are relative categories with arbitrary mapping simplicial sets, but I fail to find it. Could someone please point it out?

Comment: Given that (as you point out) there must be a mistake and that the argument you give is at most a sketch,it is hard to give an answer that isn't just "if you write a detailed argument, you will get stuck" - it would therefore help both you and potential answerers to write out a more detailed argument :)

Comment: Alright, as I feared my reasoning is not clear enough. I actually have gone through the details, and I didn't get stuck, so I'm going to edit the question and include a more detailed argument.

Comment: Perhaps you have some mistaken preconceptions. For example, it is true that the nerve of any category is right orthogonal to the inclusion $\partial \Delta^n \hookrightarrow \Delta^n$ for all $n \ge 3$. But it is also true that every homotopy type can be realised by the nerve of some category. These facts together imply that truncatedness in this sense is not the same as homotopy truncatedness.

Comment: Relatedly, I believe it's known that the hom simplicial sets of $\mathfrak C X$ are 3-coskeletal for any simplicial set $X$, and I want to attribute this fact to Emily Riehl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. For every two objects $X, Y \in \mathcal{C}$, the hom space $L^H\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ has the right lifting property against $\partial \Delta^n \to \Delta^n$ for $n \geq 3$.

First note that the nerve of any category has the strict right lifting property against $\partial \Delta^n \to \Delta^n$ for $n \geq 3$. The space $L^H\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ is not the nerve of a category, but it is a quotient of the nerve a category (See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+localization#DwyerKanCalculating)). Call this nerve $N\mathcal{D}(X,Y)$. Your argument can be summarized by saying that any map $\partial \Delta^n \to L^H\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ can be factored through $N\mathcal{D}(X,Y)$, where we can solve the lifting problem and then project back into $L^H\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$. (This is the "unreducing" part of your argument).

Note that what I just said does not yet prove that the lift to $L^H\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ is unique. This would require a further argument about what happens when you have two different lifts $\partial \Delta^n \to N\mathcal{D}(X,Y)$. This might be possible - I am not 100% sure though.

In any case, the simplicial set $L^H\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ is not a Kan complex (usually). So, as pointed out in the comments by Zhen Lin, having the right lifting property against $\partial \Delta^n \to \Delta^n$ for $n \geq 3$ does not tell us about the higher homotopy groups of  $L^H\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$. Indeed, as you correctly observe, there are relative categories which allow you to realize $L^H\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ as any homotopy type you like.